# ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, frozenlist, multidict, yarl

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-c++, pip, aiohttp

I'm trying to install some Python packages using `pip` but I'm encountering the following error:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build aiohttp frozenlist multidict yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, frozenlist, multidict, yarl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I've tried installing Microsoft C++ Build Tools from the provided link, but the issue persists.

##### Additional Details:

- Operating System: (Windows 10 & 11)
- Python Version: (3.12.0)
- Command Used: (pip install openai)

Has anyone faced a similar issue or have any idea how to resolve this?

##### What I've Tried:

1. Installed Microsoft C++ Build Tools from the provided link.
2. Restarted the computer.
3. Ran `pip install --upgrade pip` to make sure pip is up-to-date.
4. Tried installing the packages individually.
5. Checked for similar issues online but couldn't find a solution that works for me.

Despite these steps, the issue persists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [warning C4996: 'Py\_OptimizeFlag': deprecated in 3.12 aiohttp/\_websocket.c(3042): error C2039: 'ob\_digit': is not a member of '\_longobject'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77388920/warning-c4996-py-optimizeflag-deprecated-in-3-12-aiohttp-websocket-c3042)